# Trace of $H^1(\Omega)$ function onto regular hypersurface inside $\Omega$ (and not the boundary)?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, trace-map

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth domain in 2D and let $S$ be a closed smooth surve inside $\Omega$

Do functions in $H^1(\Omega)$ have a trace on $S$ and does it follow that $u \in H^1(\Omega) \implies u|_{S} \in H^{\frac 12}(S)$?

I.e. is the fractional Sobolev space the correct trace space?

Comment: If $f(x,y) = \sum_{n,m} c_{n,m} e^{2i \pi (nx+my)}, \sum_{n,m} |c_{n,m}|^2 (1+n^2+m^2 ) < \infty$ then 

$f(x,0) = \sum_{n}(\sum_m c_{n,m}) e^{2i \pi nx}$  and $\sum_{n}|\sum_m c_{n,m}|(1+|n|^{1-2\epsilon})$ $ \le \sum_{n}\sqrt{(\sum_l 1/(1+|l|^{1/2+\epsilon})^2) \sum_m |c_{n,m}(1+|m|^{1/2+\epsilon})|^2}(1+|n|^{1-2\epsilon}) $ so $f(.,0) \in H^{1/2-\epsilon}$. Won't it work the same way when $S$ is any finite length closed smooth curve ?